# Persistent login data after refreshing page in React

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, reactjs

I have created a `login page` in React which takes user data and opens a `User Page` with the user's name. When I refresh this page again, it loses user data. I am storing user data in redux store.

If I want to make it persistent what should I do? Should I use local storage or create a Mysql DB to store data? Which one is better for a large application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a backend job to me ...
Your persistence should probably be on the express side of your application.

If you really want to do it with React only check this :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-react-session

There are a lot of resources on the Web about sessions :

- https://auth0.com/blog/adding-authentication-to-your-react-flux-app/
- https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/data-persistence-and-sessions-with-react--cms-25180
- ...